# Import/create a new template in Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I am following these steps: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Creating+a+page+template. I'm stopped at creating a page definition.

**Magnolia does not see my helloWorld.jsp template**. I'm using the Enterprise Edition (free trial) if it matters. I watched all tutorials, but I can not find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it probably matters.

When you are using EE, you can have defined multiple sites in single server and you don't necessarily want to have each template available in each site you define. So you need to tell Magnolia for which site you want to enable this template. To enable this template for all sites, go to STK group in AdminCentral and open SiteDefinitons app there. In Site Definitions, go to `/default/templates/availability/templates` and register your template there by creating Node named `helloWorld` with property `id` set to value `templating:pages/helloWorld`   (ID is always in format `module-name:path-to-template-from-templates-folder`)

HTH,
Jan